# chromium/ubuntu: where is "rest of" history stored?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, history

I know that chromium (under xubuntu, default package install) usually saves its profile and history data under `~/.config/chromium`. Today, I removed that directory and `~/.cache/chromium`, and restarted the computer and chromium (to try and fix a corrupt profile). As expected, chromium mostly looked like a fresh install - except that `Ctrl+H` still brought up some of my browsing history, and when I went to set my homepage/new tab pages, it still suggested the ones I had before. I was wondering, where's the "rest of" the history saved, since it clearly survived me deleting the main profile directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Ubuntu 12.04 LTS I've just tried your procedure with Chromium v. 28.0.1500.71 and I'd say that Chromium at clean start imports the history from Firefox default profile that is stored inside ~/.mozilla/firefox.

You can clear the Firefox history with **History** > **Clear Recent History** and additional options that are suitable to you.